# Array of random numbers is the same each time

Tags: c++, xcode6

I'm making a vector program that is supposed to be producing 3 different vectors each time.

This is the code I have so far:

GenerateVector.h file:

```c++
#ifndef Vector_GenerateVector_h
#define Vector_GenerateVector_h
#endif

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class FourVector
{
    int x, y, z, t;
public:
    FourVector (int a, int b, int c, int d);
    int getX() {return x;}
    int getY() {return y;}
    int getZ() {return z;}
    int getT() {return t;}
};

FourVector::FourVector (int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
    z = c;
    t = d;
}

string toString(FourVector vec) //get vector function
{
    ostringstream s; //making a new string stream
    s << "("<< vec.getX() << ", " << vec.getY() << ", " << vec.getZ() << ", " << vec.getT() << ")"; // append to string stream
    string combinedString = s.str(); //cast string stream to a string
    return combinedString; //return string.
}

FourVector genVector()
{
    int x = rand() % 10;
    int y = rand() % 10;
    int z = rand() % 10;
    int t = rand() % 10;

    FourVector  v (x, y, z, t);

    return v;
}

vector<FourVector> createArrayFourVectors()
{
    vector<FourVector> vecs; //create array of threevectors.

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        FourVector v = genVector();
        vecs.assign(i, v); // assign threevectors to the array to fill it up.
    }
    return vecs;
}
```

main.cpp file:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include "GenerateVector.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int seed = static_cast<int>(time(nullptr));
    srand(seed);

    vector<FourVector> v = createArrayFourVectors();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        FourVector tv = v[i];
        cout << toString(tv) << endl;
    }
}
```

(5, 1, 4, 8)

(5, 1, 4, 8)

(0, 0, 0, 0)

Program ended with exit code: 0

1st problem is: I do not understand why there is only 2 vectors produced instead of 3.

2nd problem is: Why is vector number 1 and vector number 2 always the same? I have used srand() only once, in the beginning of my main function and still I have this problem. I figured my computer was too fast for the time to change significantly to produced another set of random numbers, but trying to insert usleep(1000000) made no difference.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the code for `createArrayFourVectors`?

Comment: `srand()` take an `unsigned int` argument, not `int`, could it be one of the issues?

Comment: @BlackFrog, its in the first code snippet block of code.

Comment: @vard, I have also tried srand(time(NULL)); which makes no difference :/

Comment: @vard This would probably throw a compile warning, but certainly wouldn't produce the behavior the OP is describing.

Comment: @Cyber I suggest the same, anyway we should be careful about parameters types, because it leads to complicated bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `vecs.assign(i, v);`. This form of `assign` takes an integer and an object, and sets the vector equal to that number of copies of the object. You have a loop over `i` taking the values 0, 1, and 2, so in the last iteration of the loop you will be setting two copies of your `FourVector` object. This means the first two elements of `vec` will be identical copies, and the length of the vector will be `2` and any attempt to access beyond that will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I should have seen that coming actually!

Answer (score 3):

Its because of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The [`std::vector::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) function replaces an *existing* entry in the vector, but the vector is empty so you're writing into a non-existing entry in the vector.

Easy solution? Use `push_back` instead.

Comment: Brilliant! This fixed it for me! I would appreciate it if you could expand on the answer a little bit so I can understand better why it didn't work. Or maybe suggest a link that I can read? :) Thanks though for the brilliant solution. Upvoted and marked as accepted!

Comment: @PhotonicBoom If an vector is empty, i.e. its length is zero, there are no valid indexes in the vector, everything is out of bounds. The `assign` function assumes the index is valid, and try to replace the entry with the specified index with the specified value. But if the size is zero and there are no valid indexes, what will it replace?

Comment: @PhotonicBoom the solution is correct, but the reason isn't.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see now, this is all very clear. Thank you!

Comment: Although the program in the question does not do what is intended, it does not invoke undefined behaviour. The object `vecs` is initialised to an empty vector, and it is perfectly legal to invoke the `assign` method on an empty vector. In fact any previous value will be discarded by `assign` anyway, and this is the real problem: the final call of `assign` discards previously assigned values, and writes `i=2` identical entries into `vecs`.

Comment: Oh damn, I misread the `assign` function reference. @PhotonicBoom While the solution works, the reason is totally wrong, please accept the answer from Mark Ransom instead, so I can delete this one.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I wouldn't be offended if you just fixed your answer.

Comment: @Done. No need to delete it in my opinion. After all the solution genuinely helped me. Maybe edit it and say why it is wrong? From my little experience programming is literally learning through mistakes :)